# Dropbox API UploadAsync never returns

Tags: c#, api, upload, dropbox

My code for uploading a file to Dropbox is super simple... but it never returns from the call to UploadAsync... the file actually ends up in Dropbox perfectly, but it never returns from the function call... any idea what I might be doing wrong?

```
using Dropbox.Api;
using Dropbox.Api.Files;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test
{
    public static class DropboxService
    {    
        private static string DropboxAccessToken = "...";

        public async static Task<bool> UploadFile(Stream stream, string path, string filename)
        {
            using (var client = new DropboxClient(DropboxAccessToken))))
            {
                var updated = await client.Files.UploadAsync(
                    Path.Combine(path, filename),
                    WriteMode.Overwrite.Instance,
                    body: stream);
                // never returns from UploadAsync
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I plugged this in to a new project and the method returned for me. How big is the data that you're trying to upload? Is there anything about the stream itself or the network connection you're using that would prevent it from completing the upload? Also, how are you checking that `UploadAsync` isn't returning? You don't seem to be using the return value `updated`.

Comment: The file is pretty small (a csv with a dozen rows in it)... and the file actually makes it up to Dropbox... I put a breakpoint and stepped over the function call... and it never came back... well at least it wasn't something stupid... but now to figure out what's up... Thanks for double checking me.

Comment: @BrianRice, did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: No I haven't figured out the problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why, but it worked for me.

var response = dbx.Files.UploadAsync(folder + "/" + file, WriteMode.Overwrite.Instance, body: stream).Result;